# Mouse top left coordinates become negative

Tags: c#, xna, mouse, coordinates

I am working on a game and I am in a very very very early stages of it.

Right now if I press CTRL+S, I create a ship (sprite) at the mouse coordinates. Clicking multiple times creates a new ship each time at mouse coordinates. When right clicking anywhere makes the last created ship move to that mouse location.

In the main Game1.cs file in the Draw method I display a bunch of debug info, including mouse X and Y coordinates.

I noticed that ships move in a weird path, not exactly towards the mouse coordinates. So I thought it was a math error or something, until I noticed mouse coordinates - top left coordinates suddenly became negative.

When debugging this issue, I would step-by-step look for top left coordinates of `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Mouse.GetState()` in the watch window and I noticed that when I create an instance of a ship, which inherits from Entity, which inherits from Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game - as soon as Entity constructor is hit, the top left coordinates are shifted into negative.

WHY the heck is this happening and how do I prevent this?

Thank you

PS: some more info that may help:
- I have 2 monitors
- playing in windowed or fullscreen mode does not help

EDIT: If I remove `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game` inheritance from the `Entity` class, the problem disappears. I would still like to know why this is happening.

Comment: It's happening because making your entities inherit from `Game` doesn't make any sense.  There should only be one instance of `Game` in your game - the game itself!

Comment: Thanks.. i don't know where i got that inheritance from. I was following 2 or 3 different XNA tutorials and must have mixed up the code or something, resulting in this odd side effect.